# Laravel-localization redirect issue

Tags: laravel, redirect, localization

I'm trying to set up a good localization system in a Laravel App. Basically what I am after is this:
If a user is logged in and selects a language, I want to store that value and next time he logs in, the system automatically redirects him with the correct locale in the url.
If a user is not logged in, but have selected a language, I want that stored in the sessions, and use that session to correctly set the locale.
If the user has not selected a language, I want to use http://www.wipmania.com/ to set the locale.

I am able to store the selected values in my Users table and sessions. The problem is how to handle the redirects. I tried to set up a beforeFilter like this:

```
if(\Auth::check()) {
   $user = \User::find(\Auth::user()->id);
   if($user->localization != NULL) {
     \LaravelLocalization::setLocale($user->localization);
     \Redirect::to(\LaravelLocalization::getLocalizedURL($user->localization));
            } else if(\Session::get('theSetLocale', 'none') != 'none') {
                \LaravelLocalization::setLocale(\Session::get('theSetLocale', 'none'));
                \Redirect::to(\LaravelLocalization::getLocalizedURL(\Session::get('theSetLocale', 'none')));
            } else {
                $ip = \Request::getClientIp();  
                $thestrings = 'http://api.wipmania.com/' . $ip . '?' . 'www.markmaster.com';
                $country = file_get_contents($thestrings); 
                if ($country == 'NO') {
                    \LaravelLocalization::setLocale('no');
                    \Redirect::to(\LaravelLocalization::getLocalizedURL( 'no'));
                } else if ($country == 'SE') {
                    \LaravelLocalization::setLocale('se');
                    \Redirect::to(\LaravelLocalization::getLocalizedURL( 'se'));
                } else if ($country == 'DK') {
                    \LaravelLocalization::setLocale('dk');
                    \Redirect::to(\LaravelLocalization::getLocalizedURL( 'dk'));
                } else {
                    \LaravelLocalization::setLocale('en');
                    \Redirect::to(\LaravelLocalization::getLocalizedURL( 'en'));
                }
            }
            }else if(\Session::get('theSetLocale', 'none') != 'none') {
              \LaravelLocalization::setLocale(\Session::get('theSetLocale', 'none'));
              \Redirect::to(\LaravelLocalization::getLocalizedURL(\Session::get('theSetLocale', 'none')));
        } else {
            $ip = \Request::getClientIp();  
            $thestring = 'http://api.wipmania.com/' . $ip . '?' . 'markmaster.com';
            $country = file_get_contents($thestring); 
            if ($country == 'NO') {
                \LaravelLocalization::setLocale('no');
                \Redirect::to(\LaravelLocalization::getLocalizedURL( 'no'));
            } else if ($country == 'SE') {
                \LaravelLocalization::setLocale('se');
                \Redirect::to(\LaravelLocalization::getLocalizedURL( 'se'));
            } else if ($country == 'DK') {
                \LaravelLocalization::setLocale('dk');
                \Redirect::to(\LaravelLocalization::getLocalizedURL( 'dk'));
            } else {
                \LaravelLocalization::setLocale('en');
                \Redirect::to(\LaravelLocalization::getLocalizedURL( 'en'));
            }
        }
```

While this does not work, it might help you guys understand what I am trying to achieve.